# How to find all pages that use a Master Page in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, master-pages, resharper

Is there a way to find all web pages that implement a specific master page in Visual Studio?

I'm looking for a shortcut like shift F12 that will find all usages of a master page. When I do it on the master page class name it only takes me to the design view instead of showing all pages that use it.

I do have Resharper if there is something in there that will help.

I know that I can use the Find dialog but that is not as nice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That would be *very* hard to do. You can set master pages in the aspx-files, web.config or in the Page_PreInit event, which make it impossible to know exactly which master page is going to be used.

What MasterPage to you think is used here?

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object o)
{
  this.Master = GetMasterFromDataBase(HttpContext.Current.User.Username);
}
```

As you can see, there is no way to be sure which master page is really used.

Comment: Thats a good point, but all ours are declared declaritively in the aspx so it seems odd that I can't easily navigate to them from the master page class.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that the FindDialog isn't that good... and I would agree if I'm was just using the Find Next dialog. But the "Find All" will display a list of all of the pages, then you can double click on each item in the list (as it stays open).

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or press the folder icon with the binoculars).

Answer (score 2):

You have this functionality now in ReSharper 5.0.